# How to persist a property of type List<Object> in JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jakarta-ee, payara

What is the best way to get a List with Objects persisted? I'm using JavaEE 7 with JPA. Object B is also an Entity.

**My Model**

```
@Entity
public class ObjectA implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    // What should I use here?
    private List<ObjectB> objectList;

    public ObjectA () {
        this.objectList = new ArrayList<ObjectB>();
    }
}
```

**My JPA Calls**

```
@Stateless
@JPA
public class ObjectJPA{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ObjectProjectPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    // How can I insert a record in the table for objectList here?
    public void insertIntoObjectList(ObjectB objectB) {
        em.persist(objectB); // This must be wrong?
    }
}
```

What I prefer is that my database table for objectList would look like this:

```
id (ObjectA_id) | objectB_id     or    id | ObjectA_id | objectB_id
```

Comment: Is "ObjectB" class an entity? PS, It's weird to call a class "Object".

Comment: @DN1 Yes ObjectB class is an entity. Yeah I know but it's just for theoretical purpose. It could be any name of course.

Comment: So it is a 1-N or M-N relation, and you follow basic JPA docs http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#one_many_relations

Comment: @DN1 That would be an [one (ObjectA)] to [null/one to many (ObjectB)] relationship here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that it was pretty easy.

**ObjectA Model**

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable
(
    name="OBJECTA_OBJECTB",
    joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="ID") },
    inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="OBJECTB_ID", referencedColumnName="ID") }
)
private List<ObjectB> objectList;
```

**JPA CALL**

```
public void insertIntoObjectList(ObjectB object) {
    object.setSomeDataInObjectList(list); // just a random list here
    em.persist(object); 
}
```

**ObjectB Model**

```
@ManyToOne
ObjectA objectA;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **ObjectA** class should look like below.

```html
@Entity
public class ObjectA implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    // What should I use here?
    private List<ObjectB> objectList;
 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "objectB_id")
    public List<ObjectB> getObjectList() {
        return objectList;
    }

    public void setObjectList(List<ObjectB> listOfObjetB) {
        this.objectList = listOfObjetB;
    }

    public ObjectA () {
        this.objectList = new ArrayList<ObjectB>();
    }
}
```

This will create a relation between your class A and B.

Follow the example given to the below link properly. It will help you to understand the JPA one to many relationship. :)

Comment: Errm no, don't do that. Because this "answer" has put annotations on a GETTER (for `objectList`) and a FIELD (for `id`), never mind the fact that it makes assumptions about some magical field "objectB_id" in ObjectB class. Just follow the provided link which gives a clear example.